# Is it possible to add a header to all endpoints on API gateway, rather than adding to each request individually?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Rather than adding a header to each request indivdually for API Gateway, is there a way to add a header to all the endpoints that exist?

By individually, I'm referring to adding a HTTP Header to each resource:

[image]

I'd rather do this without utlizing a tool such as Swagger.

Comment: i think no but you can use cloud formation to create your resources which will be easier than doing this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, the answer is No.

However, a tool such as CloudFormation, Swagger or Terraform would make rolling out headers simpler.